# Standardizes Rows of a Pandas.DataFrame Object

Tags: python, strings, pandas

Please take a look at this little snippet of code and explicate on whether there are an efficiency enhancements that you'd make for it. It standards a row of a pandas.DataFrame by adding zeros to it so that the total length of the datum is the same as the longest datum in the column

Sample "solubility.csv" file for testing

```
SMILES,Solubility
[Br-].CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[N+](C)(C)C,-3.6161271205000003
O=C1Nc2cccc3cccc1c23,-3.2547670983
[Zn++].CC(c1ccccc1)c2cc(C(C)c3ccccc3)c(O)c(c2)C([O-])=O.CC(c4ccccc4)c5cc(C(C)c6ccccc6)c(O)c(c5)C([O-])=O,-3.9244090954
C1OC1CN(CC2CO2)c3ccc(Cc4ccc(cc4)N(CC5CO5)CC6CO6)cc3,-4.6620645831
```

```
def generate_standard():
    dataframe = pd.read_csv('solubility.csv', usecols = ['SMILES','Solubility'])
    dataframe['standard'],longest = '',''
    for _ in dataframe['SMILES']:
        if len(str(_)) > len(longest):
            longest = str(_)
        continue
    # index,row in dataframe
    for index,row in dataframe.iterrows():
        # datum from column called 'SMILES'
        smi = row['SMILES']
        # zeros = to difference between longest datum and current datum
        zeros = (0 for x in range(len(longest) - len(str(smi))))
        # makes the zeros into type str
        zeros_as_str = ''.join(str(x) for x in zeros)
        # concatenate the two str
        std = str(smi) + zeros_as_str
        # and place it in a new column called standard at the current index
        dataframe.at[index,'standard'] = std                                                                                                                                
    return dataframe,longest
```

Comment: Where did `longest` come from in your snippet? Add more context with a minimal and testable dataframe fragment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Edits have been made. Hope this helps you. Thanks for taking some time to look at my code.

Comment: I will upvote both of these when I have 15 rep. But regardless, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ways to improve and optimize:

- function `generate_standard` is named too general whereas it loads concrete csv file `'solubility.csv'` and processes a particular column `'SMILES'`.
  A more maintainable and flexible way is to make the function more decoupled and unified such that it accepts an input *csv* file name and the crucial column name. 
  The main purpose can be described as ***"aligning a specific column's values length by the longest value"***.
  Let's give a function the appropriate name with the following signature:

  ```
  def align_col_length(fname, col_name):
      """Align a specified column's values length by the longest value"""
      df = pd.read_csv(fname)
      ...
  ```
- finding the longest string value in `SMILES` column.
  Instead of `for` loop, since you are dealing with `pandas` which is powerful enough and allows `str` accessor on `pd.Series` objects (points to column values in our case):

> `Series` and `Index` are equipped with a set of string processing
>   methods that make it easy to operate on each element of the array.
>   Perhaps most importantly, these methods exclude missing/NA values
>   automatically. These are accessed via the `str` attribute and
>   generally have names matching the equivalent (scalar) built-in string
>   methods

Thus, applying a flexible chain `df[col_name].str.len()` + [`pd.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) we would be able to get the row label/position of the maximum value.
Then, just easily get the column's longest value by the row position using:

```
longest = df.loc[df[col_name].str.len().idxmax(), col_name]
```

- *New* `dataframe['standard']` column with padded values. 
  It only remains to apply a flexible one-liner using [`pd.Series.str.pad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html) routine (to pad the `col_name` values up to width of `len(longest)`)

---

The final optimized function now becomes a more concise and `pandas`-flavored:

```
import pandas as pd

def align_col_length(fname, col_name):
    """Align a specified column's values length by the longest value"""
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    longest = df.loc[df[col_name].str.len().idxmax(), col_name]
    df['standard'] = df[col_name].str.pad(len(longest), side='right', fillchar='0')

    return df, longest
```

---

Testing:

```
df, longest = align_col_length('solubility.csv', col_name='SMILES')

print('longest SMILE value:', longest)
print('*' * 30)   # just visual separator
print(df)
```

The output:

```
longest SMILE value: [Zn++].CC(c1ccccc1)c2cc(C(C)c3ccccc3)c(O)c(c2)C([O-])=O.CC(c4ccccc4)c5cc(C(C)c6ccccc6)c(O)c(c5)C([O-])=O
******************************
                                                                                                     SMILES  ...                                                                                                  standard
0  [Br-].CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[N+](C)(C)C                                                                       ...  [Br-].CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[N+](C)(C)C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1  O=C1Nc2cccc3cccc1c23                                                                                      ...  O=C1Nc2cccc3cccc1c23000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2  [Zn++].CC(c1ccccc1)c2cc(C(C)c3ccccc3)c(O)c(c2)C([O-])=O.CC(c4ccccc4)c5cc(C(C)c6ccccc6)c(O)c(c5)C([O-])=O  ...  [Zn++].CC(c1ccccc1)c2cc(C(C)c3ccccc3)c(O)c(c2)C([O-])=O.CC(c4ccccc4)c5cc(C(C)c6ccccc6)c(O)c(c5)C([O-])=O
3  C1OC1CN(CC2CO2)c3ccc(Cc4ccc(cc4)N(CC5CO5)CC6CO6)cc3                                                       ...  C1OC1CN(CC2CO2)c3ccc(Cc4ccc(cc4)N(CC5CO5)CC6CO6)cc300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few comments:

- In `pandas` it is customary to use `df` as a generic name for a dataframe. It is well understood and a lot shorter than `dataframe`, which is why I will use it in the rest of this answer.
- Use `_` only as an unused placeholder. If you want to do something with the object, give it a name. Even a single character name like `s` for a string is more meaningful than `_`.
- You don't need to initialize variables before using them. `longest = ''` is unneeded.
- The first for loop could be implemented using the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function using the `key` parameter:

  ```
  longest = max(dataframe['SMILES'], key=len)`.
  ```
- But `pandas` has [vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html). Instead of `max`, you can use

  ```
  longest = df.SMILES[df.SMILES.str.len().idxmax()]
  ```
- Instead of `str.join`ing a generator of zeros, use string multiplication:

  ```
  zeros_as_str = "0" * (len(longest) - len(smi))
  ```
- But what you really want to do is to use [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust), which is also vectorized by `pandas`. This makes the whole function a lot shorter (and probably faster, too, because the iteration does not necessarily happen in Python anymore). You also don't actually need the longest string, you just need its length:

  ```
  def generate_standard():
      df = pd.read_csv('solubility.csv', usecols=['SMILES','Solubility'])
      longest = df.SMILES.str.len().max()
      df["standard"] = df.SMILES.str.ljust(longest, "0")
      return df, longest
  ```
- Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using a space after a comma in a tuple, but no spaces around the `=` when using it for keyword arguments.